# How to remove item using shopping cart session Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am currently developing an ecommerce system and I am already in the part of ordering module. I am using the shopping cart of Codeigniter and it is my first to do it.

Done in a part of add to cart but having problem in remove single item in cart session. When I clicked the Remove, everything in my cart will be remove.

Question: How can I remove a single item in my cart?

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>
        <tr>
              <td><?= $items['name']?></td>
              <td><?= $items['qty']?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center"><span>&#8369;<?= $this->cart->format_number($items['price'])?></span></td>
              <td style="text-align:center"><span>&#8369;<?= $items['subtotal']?></span></td>
              <td><a href="<?= base_url().'user/remove_cart'?>"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"><?= $this->cart->remove($items['rowid'])?>REMOVE</i></button></a></td> 
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function remove_cart($rowid)
    {
        $removed_cart = array(
            'rowid'         => $rowid,
            'qty'           => 0
        );
         $this->cart->update($removed_cart);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked what is coming in $rowid

Comment: <?= $this->cart->remove($items['rowid'])?> there is no function like $this->cart_remove()  please reffer https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

Comment: remove($rowid). how can I use this?

Comment: don't call cart remove function in the for loop. Just post the rowID to controller and remove it.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html?highlight=cart#CI_Cart::remove

Comment: So when should I use the remove()?

Comment: @Angel Usually updating a product qty to 0, will automatically remove the product. The same goes on, when deleting just update the qty to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code removes the cart items

```
<td><a href="<?= base_url().'user/remove_cart'?>"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"><?= $this->cart->remove($items['rowid'])?>REMOVE</i></button></a></td>
```

this part

```
<?= $this->cart->remove($items['rowid'])?>
```

Here it gets removed

remove the code and you can try like this.

```
<td>
      <a href="<?= base_url().'user/remove_cart/'.$items['rowid']; ?>">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">REMOVE</i></button>
      </a>
```

Comment: Why sir? When do I need to use the remove()?

Comment: i am not telling  you to use remove(), analyze my above code,  i have removed the code from yours  <?= $this->cart->remove($items['rowid'])?> and added  <a href="<?= base_url().'user/remove_cart/'.$items['rowid']; ?>

Comment: Yes, I already noticed it.I just want to know when/how should I use the remove()

Comment: this helps you to understand how to use and how it works https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#CI_Cart::remove and update https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#CI_Cart::update

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to remove a row by clicking a button is using JQuery
This is my solution :

**HTML , PHP :**

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td><!--your PHP code--></td>
        <td><!--your PHP code--></td>
        <td><span>&#8369;<!--your PHP code--></span></td>   
        <td><a href="<!--your PHP code-->"><button class="remove">REMOVE</button></a></td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><!--your PHP code--></td>
        <td><!--your PHP code--></td>
        <td><span>&#8369;<!--your PHP code--></span></td>   
        <td><a href="<!--your PHP code-->"><button class="remove">REMOVE</button></a></td> 
     </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })
});
```

that is the link to the example : 
http://tpcg.io/J0Uv2H

Comment: Where is the connection between the question and the above answer? is there any javascript or jquery in question ?

Comment: @Nobita he want remove an item from a table.. maybe can help...  let him choose...

Comment: Leave guys. The javascript tag also there

Comment: Read the question and get the issue "When I clicked the Remove, everything in my cart will be remove."

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Shopping cart class from Codeigniter. It has been deprecated.

You should implement your own. We are using Codeigniter for our custom ecommerce app, and i can tell you that using makes much more sense. I have never seen any point in using Codeigniter shoping cart class.

It is nothing more than wrapper around Session.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this one:

```
function remove($id) {

        if ($id === "all"){
        $this->cart->destroy();
        }
        else{
        // Destroy selected rowid in session.
        $data = array(
        'rowid' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'qty' => 0
        );
        $this->cart->update($data);
        }
        $this->load->view('users/cart_function');
    }
```

check $rowid has a value.